# How to get sequence of characters that are specific using Regex

Tags: python, string, extract

I'm trying to get two separate regex matches of a string:

```
a = " practicing_regular_expressions_z1_test_y3_test_y11_1930 "
```

I need to get only "y3" and "y11" separately.

I'm a beginner and would appreciate any help.

Comment: Use the `re` builtin library

Comment: You can use a.find('y3') or import re and then re.search('y3',a)

Comment: Hi, I'm trying  using " r'_y\d{1}' ", but when I print the result, it does not print me the desired sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import re

a = " practicing_regular_expressions_z1_test_y3_test_y11_1930 "

re.findall(r"y\d+", a)  # ['y3', 'y11']
```

This is a bit quick and dirty, but it works. The `\d+` means 1 or more digits so it will capture both.